# update query in access db having text datatype

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, oledb

```
strSQL = @"UPDATE UserLogin 
                       SET UserPassword= @paramUserPassword
                       WHERE UserId= @paramUserId";
            objOleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connectionstring);

            objOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramUserId", "1");
            objOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramUserPassword", "ooo");

            objOleDbComm.ExecuteNonQuery(objOleDbCommand);
```

Where UserPassword and UserId have text datatype.
table is not update with above query.

Comment: try wrapping your @paramUserPassword in single quote

Answer (score 1):

You're setting up your `OleDbCommand` query parameters incorrectly.  As stated in the MSDN article for the [OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx), the OleDbCommand object does not support named parameters the way you're using them.  You'll use a question mark character as placeholders for your parameters and then declare your parameters in the exact same order as they appear in your query.

Try this:

```
var strSQL = @"UPDATE UserLogin 
               SET    UserPassword= ?
               WHERE  UserId= ?";

using (var myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring)) 
using (var objOleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, myConnection)) {

    // Parameter used for the SET statement declared before the parameter for the WHERE
    // clause since this parameter is used before that one in the SQL statement.
    objOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramUserPassword", "ooo");
    objOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramUserId", "1");

    myConnection.Open();
    objOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This code also demonstrates the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), which will ensure disposal of the resources used by the `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` objects when the block is exited.